# Raspberry Pi3 - XBee not working

Tags: pi-3, xbee

I bought two XBee S2C and a RPi3. I can send data from my RPi3-Xbee to the computer-Xbee but i cannot receive. I have followed the below steps:

1- change uart from bluetooth to pins:

```
a- core_freq=250
b- force_turbo=0
c- dtoverlay=pi3-disable-bt
d- enable_uart=1
```

2- my pytho program is

```
!usr/bin/python
from xbee import XBee
import serial

ser=serial('/dev/ttyAMA0',9600)
while True:
    ser.write('i')
    response=ser.readline().strip()
    print(serial)

ser.close()
```

Did I miss somthing ? I am trying to solve it since yesterday :s

PS: when using the XCTu the two xbee communicates without any problem

Comment: why are you not printing the response?? try adding `print(response)` at the end of your while loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem.

This works for me.

1.- Add only this line to /boot/config.txt:

```
dtoverlay=pi3-disable-bt
```

2.- Stop the service:

```
sudo systemctl disable hciuart
```

3.- Important!!!! disable the serial1 to send debug output. Modify the file /boot/cmdline.txt use serial0 instead of seral1.

Now you should receive data correctly form /dev/ttyAMA0

Regards